# Search a substring using SQL in C# OleDb

Tags: sql, ms-access, substring

I have a Customers Database in MS Access.
I want to make a sql query that searches a substring from my primary key field.

For Example :

I want to select all the IDs that contain the number "35".

My DataBase **before** the SELECT statement :

[image]

My DataBase **after** the SELECT statement :

[image: Example For a wanted substring]

Is it possible ?

Comment: but.. is your primary key a string or a number?? If it is a string you should check this link out: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Access wildcard is `*` and not `%` and, AFAIK, Access doesn't support `CONTAINS` I think you really want:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID like "*35*"
```

Though based on our discussion in comments, other options (for when the `ID` field isn't a `string`) are:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Str(ID) like "*35*"
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CStr(ID) like "*35*"
```

Comment: can i use it in C# using OleDb?

Comment: I've never tried, but why not give it a go? If you run into problems, come back with another question.

Comment: It's working for string field , how can i use it for integer field ?

Comment: Within Access it seemed to work for me against integer fields without changes. However, you might want to try `WHERE str(ID) like "*35*"`.

Comment: Thank You , But i need it for C# and it doesn't work with str(ID) , It doesn't know what is str.

Comment: Hmm, can you show us your c# code in an update to the question?

Comment: Before you do, try using CStr instead of Str.

Comment: Thank You Man , Worked Like A Charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ID field is numeric,

In MsAccess:

```
Select * from myTable
where str(ID) like "*35*"
```

in SQL Server

```
Select * from myTable
where str(ID, 12, 0) like '%35%'
```

Comment: can i use it in C# using OleDb?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(20)) LIKE '%35%';
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but question was about MS Access. I don't think your code is valid there. For starters, the wildcard is `*` not `%`. As for the `CAST` ... ?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the MS Access tag. I jumped the gun there.